# Python: is it possible to default an argument to a variable from the global name space?

Tags: python

I'm wondering if I can get the following behaviour:

```
a=5

def func(arg2=a):
    bah blah
```

So when I can the function `func` with no arguments, then `a` will be taken, unless I feed something else.

Comment: Not how you probably want it. `a` is evaluated at function creation (to `5`). Later changes of `a` aren't taken into account. You can only set e.g. `None` as default, test for it at the beginning of function and set it to `a`'s value then.

Comment: Do you want the calling namespace? Or the definition namespace?

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can. The line `def func(arg2=a):` will be evaluated exactly once when your script is run, to create a function object. The default value will be bound to the object that `a` refers to at that time. This means that if you change `a` later in your script, the default argument to the function will not change. That is also the reason that you don't ever want to use [mutable containers](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) as default arguments.

If you want to use the dynamic value of the global `a`, you need to evaluate it at runtime within the function itself. An idiomatic way of doing that is

```
def func(arg2=None):
    if arg2 is None:
        arg2 = a
    blah blah blah
```

`None` is just a common value used to indicate "no input". You can use whatever actual sentinel value suits your need.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thanks

Comment: This uses the value from the namespace of definition, not the calling namespace. Using the caller's value is possible to a limited extent, but usually a bad idea.

Comment: @AlexDeft. You should clarify in your title that you want the definition namespace then. The fact that you are calling the function from the same script that you define it in is irrelevant. The `a` in the example I show will be in the module of the function, not the module you are necessarily calling it from.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica. Good catch. I answered the question in the code, not in the title. Asking for clarification from OP now. Calling namespace will indeed complicate things.

Comment: @MadPhysicist  I see how things can get complicated if we have multiple name spaces. I would do this in simple scenarios only when I have the luxury to be lazy and not send an argument.

Comment: @AlexDeft. May I suggest updating your title to say "global" instead of "calling"? It's very misleading as it stands.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica. Looks like the issue has been resolved. OP has edited their title.